# When I apply column formatting to a 'date only' date column, the time value is displayed as well

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a date column, that is set to show date only (not time), named `My Date Column`.

I have applied the column formatting below which *achieves the desired behaviour* of:

- If column value is `more than 30 days in the future`, make text color `green` and show a `CheckMark` icon
- If column value is `between today and 30 days in the future`, make text color `red` and show an `AlarmClock` icon
- If column value is `today or in the past`, make text color `red` and show an `Important` icon

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$My_x0020_Date_x0020_Column]>(@now +2592000000), 'green', if([$My_x0020_Date_x0020_Column]>@now && [$My_x0020_Date_x0020_Column]< (@now +2592000000), 'Red', 'Red'))"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 10px 0 10px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(Number([$My_x0020_Date_x0020_Column]) == 0, '', if([$My_x0020_Date_x0020_Column]>(@now +2592000000), 'CheckMark', if([$My_x0020_Date_x0020_Column]>@now && [$My_x0020_Date_x0020_Column]< (@now +2592000000), 'AlarmClock', 'Important'))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

*However*, when I change the column formatting of the last `span` from this:

```
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "elmType": "span",
   "txtContent": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, 'N/A', @currentField)"
}
```

It produces the following:

- *Desired Behaviour*:  If the field is blank, shows the text `N/A`
- *Undesired Behaviour*:  If the field is not blank, shows a `TIME` value after the `DATE` value

To clarify, it shows this:

```
29/11/2021 23:00:00
```

when it should show this:

```
29/11/2021
```

*Additionally*, the date value is different from that which is displayed when the date is *not* within an `if()` statement.  The act of including `@currentField` within the `if()` statement is altering *how* it is displayed *and the date* that is displayed.

**Question**

Why is the time value showing in the `date only` column and how can I prevent that from happening whilst still retaining the desired conditional column formatting?

**Edit**

Based on [this answer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sp-list-date-column-and-conditional-formatting-time-zone-issue/m-p/1567917/highlight/true#M43628), wrapping `@currentField` in `=toLocaleDateString()` seems to work, ie:

```
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, 'N/A', '=toLocaleDateString(@currentField)')"
}
```

However, using `toLocaleDateString()` has the *undesired behaviour* where if I enter `01/01/2021` as the date in the list item, it is being *displayed* as `31/12/2020` on the frontend.

I think this is because the method outputs values in user's local time, [(from the docs)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting):

> **toLocaleDateString()**: returns a language sensitive representation of just the date portion of a date
> `"txtContent":"=toLocaleDateString(@now)"`
> results vary based on user's locale, but en-us looks like *"2/5/2019"*

Answer (score 0):

> It may sound odd, but to display the SharePoint date format as
> DD/MM/YYYY, please leverage/consider using SharePoint calculated
> column instead of using JSON column formatting, `provided as a built-in option, to answer your question this would be the safest approach`.

In the previous answer he was leveraging locale, I don't recommend it because that serves a different purpose and should be done at a site level.

[image: Local for site level settings]

- *You can always fallback on your JSON approach, if you don't like this.*

### 1. Open your SharePoint List > All items > Add new column > More.

[image: SharePoint Online List Column formatting, Column formatting with calculated Date , Date Time Options]

---

### 2. Make a new `calculated` column using below format

```
 =TEXT(Start,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

---

### 3. Now, it should look something like this when you set it up correctly. Pay close attention that **`this is built-in SharePoint as an option`** at the very bottom.

Bonus:

---

*You can try to replace the column `placeholders` *with* `Start` there are various other formats available to you* once you follow the built in option.

```
// some more formats to check out
=TEXT(MyDateOnlyCOl,"mmm-dd-yyyy")      
=TEXT(MyDateOnlyCol,"HH-MM")
```

Comment: Steps 1, 2 and 3 are describing the same thing?  Also, does not address main issue:  How to apply conditional column formatting to a date column and ensure it only displays the date.  The suggestion, ie `Create a calculated column with the formula: =TEXT(Start,"dd/MM/yyyy")` reproduces the same value as the `Start` column, which doesn't add any value.  This adds conditional text: 
`=IF(ISBLANK([Start]),"N/A",TEXT([Start],"dd/MM/yyyy"))`, but no required color and icon formatting.  Calculated column approach also means creating an additional column for each date column you want to work with.